# async_ read_until doesn't work as expected

Tags: string, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

So I am trying to write a program that reads and writes data through a tcp socket. I can successfully accept a connection, write data to it (though the write handler doesn't work as expected?). I also want to read data through the same socket - which doesnt seem to be working. 
The class that handles all this is as follows:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;


TcpServer::TcpServer(unsigned short port = 1700)
  : ipPort(port){
  tcp::acceptor acc(svc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), ipPort));
  acc.listen();
  acc.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(&TcpServer::Accept_Handler,this, placeholders::error));

  SAY("Waiting for a New connection");
  svc.run();
}

void TcpServer::Write_Handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                  std::size_t bytes_transferred){
  std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
  if (!ec)
    {
      std::cout << "Just sent " << yawData << std::endl;
    }
}
void TcpServer::Read_Handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                std::size_t bytes_transferred){
  if (!ec)
    {
      std::string line;
     std::istream is(&input_buffer_);
     std::string test;
     is >> test;
     std::cout << "test" << test << std::endl;
     std::getline(is, line);
     if (!line.empty())
       {
     std::cout << "Recieved: " << line << std::endl;
       }
    }
  else
    std::cout << "Error reading:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
}

void TcpServer::Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec){
  if (!ec)
    {
      std::cout << "Accepted a connection! - Now switching to write mode " << std::endl;
  connectMode = 1;
    }
}

void TcpServer::Write_Data(){
  if (connectMode){
    SAY("Sent data");
    std::ostringstream ss;
    std::string sendBuffer;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    ss << yawData;
    sendBuffer = ss.str() + "\r";
    async_write(socket, buffer(sendBuffer),       boost::bind(&TcpServer::Write_Handler, this,
                      placeholders::error,
                       placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}


void TcpServer::UpdateYaw(double data) {
  yawData = data;
}  

void TcpServer::Read_Data(){
  if (connectMode){
    async_read_until(socket, input_buffer_, "\n" ,      boost::bind(&TcpServer::Read_Handler, this,
                          placeholders::error,
                               placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
}

TcpServer::~TcpServer(){
   svc.stop();
}
```

The class header goes as:

```
class TcpServer {
 private:
  io_service svc;  
  tcp::socket socket{svc};

  double yawData = 0;
  unsigned short ipPort;
  bool connectMode = 0;
  streambuf input_buffer_;
  void Write_Handler(const boost::system::error_code&,
             std::size_t);
  void Read_Handler(const boost::system::error_code&,
             std::size_t);
   void Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code&);
 public:
  TcpServer(unsigned short );
  void Write_Data();
  void Read_Data();
  void UpdateYaw(double);
  ~TcpServer();
};
```

To use this, I call Write_Data(), followed by Read_Data(). Write_Data works, but the write handler isn't called - I can recieve data on the client side. 
Read_Data() doesn't work at all. I know for sure that Data is being sent through the socket in teh format needed (ends with "\n")

Any ideas on what could possibly be wrong or, any debugging tips?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I plan to run the write_data and read_data functions from my main function as follows:

```
  TcpServer *socketObj = new TcpServer(1700);

     while ( i < 100 && trackObj->ReadTrackingState() != 0) {
      SAY("Current Yaw - %.02f", trackObj->CurrentYaw());
      socketObj->UpdateYaw(trackObj->CurrentYaw());
      socketObj->Write_Data();
      socketObj->Read_Data();
      Platform::sleepMillis(1000);
      i++;

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void TcpServer::Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Accepted a connection! - Now switching to write mode " << std::endl;
        connectMode = 1;
    }
}
```

This function ends the async processing. It doesn't schedule any more async work and therefore `io_service::run()` ends, as documented.

You want to chain directly or use `io_service::work` to keep the service running. I suggest the chaining:

```
void TcpServer::Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Accepted a connection! - Now switching to write mode " << std::endl;
        Write_Data();
    }
}
```

But...

#### HOLD ON

You'll want to carefully review all the code.

```
void TcpServer::Write_Data() {
    SAY("Sent data");
    std::ostringstream ss;
    std::string sendBuffer;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    ss << yawData;
    sendBuffer = ss.str() + "\r";
    async_write(socket, buffer(sendBuffer),
            boost::bind(&TcpServer::Write_Handler, this, placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

What's going on here? First you create a temporary stream, fail to use it to append the carriage-return, and then pass the reference to a local string to `async_write`... That can't work. It's [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

A fix:

```
void TcpServer::Write_Data() {
    SAY("Send data");
    std::ostream ss(&output_buffer_);
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << yawData << "\r";
    async_write(socket, output_buffer_,
            boost::bind(&TcpServer::Write_Handler, this, placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

### DEMO

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/317bb72c3b826fff)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

template <typename T>
static inline void SAY(T&& v) { std::cout << std::forward<T>(v) << "\n"; }

class TcpServer {
  private:
    io_service svc;
    tcp::socket socket{ svc };

    double yawData = 0;
    unsigned short ipPort;
    streambuf input_buffer_, output_buffer_;

    void Write_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &, std::size_t);
    void Read_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &, std::size_t);
    void Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &);

  public:
    TcpServer(unsigned short = 1700);
    void Write_Data();
    void Read_Data();
    void UpdateYaw(double);
    ~TcpServer();
};

TcpServer::TcpServer(unsigned short port) : ipPort(port) {
    tcp::acceptor acc(svc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), ipPort));
    acc.listen();
    acc.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(&TcpServer::Accept_Handler, this, placeholders::error));

    SAY("Waiting for a New connection");
    svc.run();
}

void TcpServer::Write_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Just sent " << yawData << std::endl;
        Read_Data();
    }
}
void TcpServer::Read_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Recieved: " << &input_buffer_ << std::endl;
    } else
        std::cout << "Error reading:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
}

void TcpServer::Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
    if (!ec) {
        std::cout << "Accepted a connection! - Now switching to write mode " << std::endl;
        Write_Data();
    }
}

void TcpServer::Write_Data() {
    SAY("Send data");
    std::ostream ss(&output_buffer_);
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << yawData << "\r";
    async_write(socket, output_buffer_,
            boost::bind(&TcpServer::Write_Handler, this, placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void TcpServer::UpdateYaw(double data) { yawData = data; }

void TcpServer::Read_Data() {
    async_read_until(socket, input_buffer_, "\n", boost::bind(&TcpServer::Read_Handler, this, placeholders::error,
                placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

TcpServer::~TcpServer() { svc.stop(); }

int main() {
    TcpServer server;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is brilliant and detailed. The reason I hadn't chained them was, I was calling the Write_Data() and Read_Data() in a loop from the main function in another file. And like you explained - that wont work because the service no longer exists.  Is there a way I can still do that? I have edited the question to add how I plan to run the communication. I am kinda lost on the documentation.

Comment: Use `io_service::work` or consider `spawn` with co-routines